# Bug in ggplot ? Or it requires an option to make it work correctly?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The plot is correct if value of x_coordinates are increased from left to right.  If one of the value is not in order, the plot is incorrect.

Please run with `x = Vn_correct`, will give the expected plot.
And run with `x = Vn_incorrect`, will give the in-corrected plot

```
library("ggplot2")

  In<- c(0.00522,0.012,0.019,0.026,0.032,0.0392,0.0463,0.172,0.325,0.462,0.576,0.713)
  Vn_correct<- c(0.89,0.92,0.952,0.963,0.975,0.988,0.993,1.089,1.162,1.218,1.247,1.282)
  #Vn_incorrect<- c(0.89,0.92,0.952,0.963,0.975,0.988,0.993,1.089,1.162,1.218,1.295,1.282)
  df<- data.frame(In,Vn)




ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Vn_correct,y=In))+geom_line()+geom_point()
```

As shown in the image above, the last three points have to go from A to B then C (not A to C then B)[image: This plot is correct]
[image: This plot is incorrect]

Comment: You want `geom_path` (points in order), not `geom_line` (points along x-axis).

Comment: Thanks Brian, I have earned a little more today.  It works as expected when I changed from geom_line to geom_path.

Comment: @joran, I don't know how to attach an image for you to see, but it works.  Please try to run it.

Comment: @joran, sorry about that.  I want a plot with whatever the data is.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the Vn_Incorrect, the last two points are swapped. 1.295 comes before 1.282. So when you restore the order as below, I could get the correct output.

```
library(ggplot2)
In<- c(0.00522,0.012,0.019,0.026,0.032,0.0392,0.0463,0.172,0.325,0.462,0.576,0.713)
Vn_correct<- c(0.89,0.92,0.952,0.963,0.975,0.988,0.993,1.089,1.162,1.218,1.247,1.282)
Vn_incorrect<- c(0.89,0.92,0.952,0.963,0.975,0.988,0.993,1.089,1.162,1.218,1.282,1.295)
df<- data.frame(In,Vn_incorrect)
Test <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Vn_incorrect,y=In))+geom_line()+geom_point()
Test
```

The output is as below. Is this what you wanted?

[image: Correct output after reordering]

Comment: Thanks a lot.  The geom_line works if value of x_coordinates in order, but geom_path works with whatever the order is.

Comment: Yes. True! (1) However, probably you want to be in more control than software deciding it for you. In this case, the error was coming from the fact that X axis was not ordered properly. If you order it properly, all is peaceful. (2) Sometime, you may actually want geom_line() and not geom_path(). May be your client wants that way. In such a case, may be it is a good idea to look at the order of the X (and/or) Y axis of the graph. Best wishes.